# jQuery's $.post returns only a blank data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to check username's availability from the database by using jQuery's $.post.
I don't know if the path is wrong or the php script is wrong but it keeps returning a **data** of blank or null perhaps. Why is that?

JS File:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#signup_username").bind("keyup blur",function(){
    $("#loading_img_username").show();
    var prompt_username = $("#signup_username").val();
    if(prompt_username != ''){

        $.post('php/check.php', {username: prompt_username} , function(data){
            $("#signup_username_status").html(data);
            $("#loading_img_username").hide();

        }).error(function(){
            $("#loading_img_username").hide();
            $("#signup_username_status").html("<span style='color:#cc2000;'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i> Cannot verify username availability.</span>");
        });
    } else{
        $("#signup_username_status").html("<span style='color:gold;'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></i> Provide your username.</span>");
        $("#loading_img_username").hide();
    }


    });
});
```

PHP FILE:

```
<?php
 $user = $_POST['username'];
  echo $user;
```

I am aware that whatever you prompt at the input field :

```
#signup_username
```

will be an output as data to be pass on a callback function at $.post

Comment: Have you looked at the call in console? If you had you would know if your path was correct as it would give you an error if it couldn't find the resource. Next check to see what you are sending to the server (in the header for the post request). You might also print in php all your $_POST vars and see if `username` is listed.

Comment: found it. the problem is in the path name. but i don't know to simplify this url: **http://localhost/project/app/views/login_register/js/php/check.php** in javascript

sorry, i'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion 1:**

jQuery his post function is using datatypes to receive information, you are using the datatype "text" on this moment. I should use XML or JSON since that's clearer to read out.

```
$.post('url', {username: prompt_username}, function( data ) {
  $("#signup_username_status").html(data.username);
  $("#loading_img_username").hide();
}, 'JSON');
```

You'll need to encode the data in PHP if you do this to:

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
die(json_encode(array('username'=>$user)));
```

**Suggestion 2:**

Does your jQuery post request not work? Debug it with the .error function it's kinda handy if you know how to use it! Here is an example of how to put out errors:

```
$.post('url', {username: prompt_username}, function( data ) {
  $("#signup_username_status").html(data.username);
  $("#loading_img_username").hide();
}, 'JSON').error(function( a,b,c ) {
  console.log(a,b,c);
});
```